# Combine dictionary of dataframes into 1 single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am looking for a solution to put all my dataframes which are in a dictionary into 1 single giant dataframe. I am relatively new to Python so I am unable to understand how to iterate over a dictionary and put all the dataframes into 1. The code I have implemented so far, is as below:

```
import sys
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import socket
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

path = 'path_to_file'

files = glob(path + '/*Mail*.xlsx')

print files

get_df = lambda f: pd.read_excel(f, sheetname=None)

dodf = {f: get_df(f) for f in files}  ### dictionary of dataframes
```

Now, I need to put all the different dataframes into 1 dataframe and then do my operations on that. Any advise would be appreciated.

I have tried this,

```
for df in dodf:
pd.concat(dodf.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

But it does not seem to work right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with dict comprehension:

```
dodf = {f: pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None) for f in files}
df = pd.concat([v for k,v in dodf.items()])
```

Or:

```
dodf = {f: pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None) for f in files}
df = pd.concat([pd.concat(v) for k,v in dodf.items()])
```

Comment: Tried that already, but it keeps giving an error : "cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object"

Comment: Glad can help ;) Nice day!

Comment: `sheetname` is now `sheet_name` according to the docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: I tried this on my own dictionary of DataFrames and get this error: `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`

Comment: @MyCarta - there is `sheet_name=None` ? It is used for get all sheetnames in orderdict of DataFrames.

Comment: @jezrael - I am sorry, my previous comment was incomplete. I have a dictionary of dataframaes created in a different way. To that one I apply the second line of your code and it throws that error. Thinking of that, perhaps I should not have added that comment, as it is a different context.

Answer (score 7):

```
df_list = [ v for k,v in dodf.items()] 
df = pd.concat(df_list ,axis=1)
```

does this work?
It also depends whether the concat is by columns or by rows...